# React-admin: How to embed leaflet in Edit/Create view, for visual address validation

Tags: leaflet, react-admin, react-leaflet

I have a Person  & Address List.

In React-admin Edit/Create view, a User may want to enter the address/city/postalcode, and would want to see a openstreetmap of that location.

How do I embed Leaflet openstreetmap in Edit/Crete view, and link it with Address fields ?  Is there a sample/blog/github that shows an example?

```js
export const PersonEdit = props => (
    <Edit title={<PersonTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput disabled source="id" />
            <TextInput source="firstName" />
            <TextInput source="lastName" />
            <TextInput source="email" />
            <TextInput source="phone1" />
            <TextInput source="phone2" />
            <TextField label="Num" source="address.streetNum" />
            <TextField label="Street" source="address.streetName" />
            <TextField label="Pcode" source="address.postalCode" />
            <XrefAccountsField label="Xref Tags" source="xrefs" />
            <DateTimeInput disabled source="createTime" />
            <DateTimeInput disabled source="updateTime" />

            <MapContainer  center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
               <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
               <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                 <Popup>
                   A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                 </Popup>
               </Marker>
             </MapContainer>

        </SimpleForm>

    </Edit>
);
```

[image]

Comment: First, add the following to index.css: .leaflet-container {
  height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: Adding that line to index.css didn't change the layout. (screenshot updated in question)

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is not all, you still need to connect leaflet.css in the head section index.html
https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/
I downloaded it and connected it locally: <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/leaflet.css"/>

Comment: Thanks, leaflet.css did help.  The map content is correct, but is placed in one corner - screenshot updated.  I'm likely missing some aspect in react-admin way of layout/sizing in Edit/Create view.

Comment: I did not use the Edit / Create forms, but created my own form based on the material-ui Card and placed the Map inside CardMedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to index.css

```css
.leaflet-container { height: 450px; width: 100%; margin: 0  }
```

Add param fullWidth to MapContainer

```js
export const PersonEdit = props => (
   ...

            <MapContainer  center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} fullWidth>
               <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
               <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                 <Popup>
                   A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                 </Popup>
               </Marker>
             </MapContainer>

        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can position it easier with a custom form layout using the `<FormWithRedirect />` component [[check here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#customizing-the-form-layout)]. In this way you can also spread the rest of the inputs in a few rows instead of one column.